# Open a Yoosee camera with OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I tried opening my Yoosee camera with OpenCV in Python but I got the error "nonmatching transport in server reply".

I referred similar topics but I've still got no results for me, my program is shown below. Could anyone help me fix it? Besides, I'm using Python 3.11.6 64-bit interpreter from Microsoft store and OpenCV 4.8.0.76. Thank you so much.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtHtQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Also you should add the [tag:python] tag.